# Pip fails to Upgrade (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, pip

When Running the command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, cmd shows no output and pip isn't getting upgraded. Tried the command as Administrator but, still the same.
[image: cmd output]

Comment: Have you checked if the python executable itself runs?

Comment: Yeah. It runs perfectly. Python and Pip are in PATH.